# How to solve a webapi error

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angularjs, asp.net-web-api

I cannot figure out why I am getting this error. It is a new project and i am using the same setup as my previous projects. If someone can point out what is not correct.

Error Message

```
    $id: "1"
     Message: "No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI 'http://localhost:55596  /api/apiClient'."
    MessageDetail: "No type was found that matches the controller named 'apiClient'."
```

Webapi config

```
 public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        // Web API configuration and services

        // Web API routes
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
           name: "ClientApi",
           routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
           defaults: new { controller = "apiClient", id = RouteParameter.Optional }
       );
    }
```

app.js

```
'use strict';
 var app = angular.module('YoungIntel', [
 'ngResource',
 'ngRoute',
 'ui.bootstrap'
 ])
app.factory('Client', function ($resource) {
return $resource('/api/apiClient/:id',
  { id: '@id' },
  { 'save': { method: 'POST' } },
  { 'update': { method: 'PUT' } },
  { 'query': { method: 'GET'}});
 });
 app.factory('ClientGet', function ($http, $q) {
   return {
    query: function () {
        var deferred = $q.defer();
        $http({ method: 'get', url: '/api/apiClient' })
                .success(function (data) {
                    deferred.resolve(data);
                }).error(function (error) {
                    deferred.reject(error);
                });
        return deferred.promise;
    }
    }
 });
```

Controller

```
//GET Clients
$scope.clientArray = {};
ClientGet.query().then(function (data) { $scope.clientArray = data; }, function (reason) { errorMngrSvc.handleError(reason); });
```

apiController

```
  public class apiClientController : ApiController
  {
    IClient _adapter;

    public apiClientController()
    {
        _adapter = new ClientDataAdapter();
    }
    public apiClientController(IClient adapter)
    {
        _adapter = adapter;
    }

    // GET api/<controller>
    public IHttpActionResult Get()
    {
        var model = _adapter.GetClients();

        return Ok(model);
    }

    // GET api/<controller>/5
    public IHttpActionResult Get(int id)
    {
        Client client = new Client();
        client = _adapter.GetClient(id);
        if (client == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }
        return Ok(client);

    }

    // POST api/<controller>

    public IHttpActionResult PostnewClient([FromBody]Client newClient)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return BadRequest(ModelState);
        }
        var client = _adapter.PostNewClient(newClient);
        return CreatedAtRoute("ClientApi", new { newClient.ClientId }, newClient);
    }

    // PUT api/<controller>/5


    public HttpResponseMessage PutNewClient(int id, Client newClient)
    {
        ApplicationDbContext db = new ApplicationDbContext();
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, ModelState);
        }

        if (id != newClient.ClientId)
        {
            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }

        db.Entry(newClient).State = EntityState.Modified;

        try
        {
            db.SaveChanges();
        }
        catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException ex)
        {
            return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotFound, ex);
        }

        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
    }

    // DELETE api/<controller>/5
    public IHttpActionResult DeleteClient(int id)
    {

        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return BadRequest(ModelState);
        }
        return Ok(_adapter.DeleteClient(id));
    }
}
```

Update

```
 public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        // Web API configuration and services

        // Web API routes
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
        name: "ClientApi",
        routeTemplate: "api/apiClient/{id}",
        defaults: new { controller = "apiClient", id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
        name: "DefaultApi",
        routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
        defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );

    }
```

Still getting the same error

Answer (score 1):

The order of routes matter. You're registering 2 identical routes so the first match executes.
Switch it to:

```
    config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
       name: "ClientApi",
       routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
       defaults: new { controller = "apiClient", id = RouteParameter.Optional }
   );

   config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
        name: "DefaultApi",
        routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
        defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
    );
```

However, now your first route will catch everything. To avoid that, you need to change it to be different than the default route. One way is to specify the template as `api/apiClient/{id}`.

Comment: I suspect something else is going on. I suggest using [WebApiRouteDebugger](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2013/04/04/debugging-asp-net-web-api-with-route-debugger.aspx) to figure out what's going wrong. If you still can't, then post a screenshot or results of the debugger output here.

Answer (score 0):

The route `api/apiClient` matches both of your routes. To fix it simply remove the second one, your route will match the first one and will arrive at the controller.

Comment: Not sure i know which one you are talking about

Comment: You should remove the one you last defined (with name `ClientApi`)